# Java method which sums two one dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods, int

I am a Java beginner and currently learning for an exam. I got a book with tasks and one task is two write a method, that sums two int arrays if both have the same length. If they do not have the same size, the result shall be null. I am using a double as value type for results who are uneven. I started with this:

```
package aufgaben;

public class Aufgabe7 {

    public static double ArrayRechner(int[] a, int [] b) {  
        double ergebnis;
        if (a.length == b.length) {
            result = a + b; // this gives me an error
            System.out.println("Fast geschafft");
        }
        else {
            result = 0.0;
        }
        System.out.println("the result is " + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

But it says at the marked code line:

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int[].

Where is my issue? What do I have to rewrite?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an overload for addition in Java arrays. You have two `int[]` instances, you could use an `IntStream` and get the `sum()` (assuming you're using Java 8+). And, please follow Java naming conventions. That might look like

```
public static double getArrayRechner(int[] a, int[] b) {
    double result = 0;
    if (a != null && b != null && a.length == b.length) {
        result = IntStream.of(a).sum() + IntStream.of(b).sum();
        System.out.println("Fast geschafft");
    }
    System.out.println("the result is " + result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Java supports using the + operation to add the contents of 2 arrays together. I would loop through both arrays and add everything up.

```
public static double ArrayRechner(int[] arrayEins, int[] arrayZwei) {
    double ergebniss = 0;
    if (arrayEins.length == arrayZwei.length) {
        for (int X = 0; X < arrayEins.length; X++) {
            ergebniss += arrayEins[X] + arrayZwei[X];
        }
    }
    return ergebniss;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the sum by using for loop to iterate through each element in both arrays. This is an intuitive and easy-understand way.

```
if (a.length == b.length) {
     for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
          result += a[i] + b[i];
     }
     System.out.println("Fast geschafft");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support operator overloading.

```
public static double ArrayRechner(int[] a, int [] b) {
        double result = 0.0;
        if (a.length > 0 && a.length == b.length) {
            int sumOfA = Arrays.stream(a).sum();
            int sumOfB = Arrays.stream(b).sum();
            result = sumOfA + sumOfB;
            System.out.println("Fast geschafft");
        }
        System.out.println("the result is " + result);
        return result;
}
```

Comment: You can just call `sum()` instead of `reduce(0, Integer::sum);`

Answer (score 0):

**Working code:**

```
public class Aufgabe7 {

    public static int result = 0;

    public static int ArrayRechner(int[] a, int[] b) {

        if (a.length == b.length) {

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                result = result + a[i] + b[i];

            }
            System.out.println("Fast geschafft");
        }

        return result;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a[] = { 1, 1, 1 };
        int b[] = { 2, 2, 2 };
        System.out.println(ArrayRechner(a, b));

    }
}
```